# Drawing multiple shapes using SFML

Tags: c++, graphics, sfml

I want to draw 5 Rectangles using SFML library in C++. When I run the code only 3 Rectangles a drawn. A part of code is below. An array of rectangles is declared and using a for loop, I have fixed there size. The conditonal statement in while loop is executed 5 times but only 3 rectangles are shown in my window. The size of my window is 800 x 1080. How can I fix it?

```
sf::RectangleShape rect[5] ; //Declaring an array of Rectangles 



int i=0, j=50, l=0;

while (window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    while(l<6){

     rect[l].setSize(sf::Vector2f(20,20));

     rect[l].setPosition(i,j);

      window.draw(rect[l]);

       window.display();

        cout<<l<<endl;

         i+=20;

           l++;
               }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are calling `window.display();` every time you draw one of the rectangles. This isn't needed because SFML has a hidden buffer that keeps track of what has been drawn. More importantly, this is problematic because SFML uses double buffering.

According to [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-draw.php)

> Calling display is also mandatory, it takes what was drawn since the
> last call to display and displays it on the window. Indeed, things are
> not drawn directly to the window, but to a hidden buffer. This buffer
> is then copied to the window when you call display -- this is called
> double-buffering.

There are three rectangles because calling display copies the current buffer to the window and then swaps to the next buffer.

1. Draw Rectangle 1 and display to show 1 rectangle and swap to the empty buffer.
2. Draw Rectangle 2 and display to show 1 rectangle and swap to the buffer that currently has 1 rectangle.
3. Draw Rectangle 3 and display to show 2 rectangle and swap to the buffer with 1 rectangle.
4. This pattern repeats for N amount of rectangles.

If you use a breakpoint and stop after each time `window.display()` is called you can see it for yourself.

Thus, the fix is to draw all of your rectangles, shapes, text, etc before calling `window.display()`. Additionally, make sure to clear the window's buffer with `window.clear()`.

Also, it is worth noting that you only have five rectangles yet you are iterating `while(l<6)`. This will result in an off by one error and you accessing an index that is out of bounds.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 400), "SFML works!");
    sf::RectangleShape rect[5];

    int i = 0, j = 50, l = 0;
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        while (l < sizeof(rect) / sizeof(rect[0])) {
            rect[l].setSize(sf::Vector2f(20, 20));

            rect[l].setPosition(i, j);

            window.draw(rect[l]);

            i += 25;

            l++;
        }
        // Reset variables.
        l = 0;
        i = 0;
        // Copy the buffer to the window.
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This program manages to chew up 60% of my (not too slow) CPU by drawing 5 rectangles. Why `pollEvent`? WHY?! Use `waitEvent`.

Comment: And/or `window.setFramerateLimit(30)`. That would `sleep` nicely. (Obviously just for reference/reminder, not telling to add cruft like that to an example.)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your if statement by a for loop iterating on the rectangles and displaying them.
You could also set the rectangles positions during their initialization instead of every main loop iteration.
Don't forget to clear the window using window.clear(sf::Color::Black) too.

Comment: while (l<6) {

rect [l ] . setSize ( sf::Vector2f(20,20) ) ;

rect [ l ]. setPosition (i,j);


window. draw (  rect  [  l  ]  ) ;

window.display();

i+=20;

l++;
}